# Maven Appassembler plugin - stdout and/or stderr redirection

Tags: java, bash, shell, maven, appassembler

I am migrating one java project into Maven and we are using Appassembler maven plugin (version 1.3) for generating shell start script. My problem is how to redirect stdout and/or output of java program? This Appassembler's pom.xml configuration

```
        <program>
          <mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</mainClass>
          <commandLineArguments>
            <commandLineArgument>arg1</commandLineArgument>
            <commandLineArgument>arg2</commandLineArgument>
          </commandLineArguments>
          <name>app</name>
        </program>
```

generates:

```
exec "$JAVACMD" $JAVA_OPTS \
  $EXTRA_JVM_ARGUMENTS \
  -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
  -Dapp.name="app" \
  -Dapp.pid="$$" \
  -Dapp.repo="$REPO" \
  -Dbasedir="$BASEDIR" \
  com.mycompany.app.App \
  arg1 arg2 "$@"
```

Parameters placeholder ($@) is the last generated token in the start script.

Comment: Why not simply redirecting the output of the generated script instead of the java call which is more abvious than redirecting the output of the jre call.

Comment: Because we will be sure that some uncaught exception in application threads will be logged. With your approach it would rely on script's invoker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a workaround on this problem. Fortunately the parameters placeholder is on the same line as generated command line arguments. So this pom.xml configuration:

```
<commandLineArguments>
    <commandLineArgument>"$@"</commandLineArgument>
    <commandLineArgument>&gt;&gt;out.log</commandLineArgument>
    <commandLineArgument>2&gt;&amp;1</commandLineArgument>
    <commandLineArgument>#</commandLineArgument>
</commandLineArguments>
```

will generate the script:

```
....
com.mycompany.app.App \
"$@" >>out.log 2>&1 # "$@"
```

Hash is comment in bash so the last parameter placeholder will be ignored and this hack will do the redirecting job.